# How to translate woocommerce my account psub pages urls

Tags: woocommerce

I can't find how to translate woocommerce my account sub pages urls (as they are not really pages). it's not in po files as they are not strings.

edit-account
orders
downloads
edit-address
payment
...

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry super easy

You can do it in woocommerce -> settings -> advanced